# Building singularity image: "Failure while installing base packages"

Tags: singularity-container

When trying to build the Singularity image for this package:
https://bitbucket.org/MAVERICLab/vcontact2.git

I get:

```
{cut}
I: Configuring login...
I: Configuring adduser...
I: Configuring apt...
I: Configuring util-linux...
I: Configuring mount...
I: Configuring sysvinit-utils...
I: Configuring libc-bin...
I: Unpacking the base system...
W: Failure while installing base packages.  This will be re-attempted up to five times.
W: See /usr/local/var/singularity/mnt/container/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details
```

I have:

- Singularity 2.5.2-dist
- Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (I installed via apt-get: dh-autoreconf, build-essential,     libarchive-dev, debootstrap)

The error look obscure to me, looks like some packages were not available for download. What should I try to fix this? (I'd like not to use a newer version of Singularity)

Comment: Please consider upgrading (or ask your cluster admin to upgrade) Singularity to v2.6.1. There are significant security vulnerabilities in all other versions of the v2. In 2.5.2 it's CVE-2018-19295, with more details available here: https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/releases/tag/2.6.1

Comment: Are you able to access the `debootstrap.log` to see what it was that failed? I'm able to replicate the error using ubuntu:xenial docker image, though the debootstrap succeeds using on my host OS with 18.04 LTS. The steps involving conda will fail as they are though.

Comment: @tsnowlan I wanted to try Ubuntu 18.04 using a Docker container, but this brings new problems: `/usr/sbin/debootstrap: 1455: /usr/sbin/debootstrap: cannot create /usr/local/var/singularity/mnt/container/test-dev-null: Permission denied
E: Cannot install into target '/usr/local/var/singularity/mnt/container' mounted with noexec or nodev`

Comment: When building singularity images in docker you have to also add the `--privileged` flag to `docker  run ...` or else it will fail, though that error message doesn't look too familiar. The build process is still failing for me though, as their definition file has some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to modify the definition file and use a different bootstrap source, the following builds successfully on 18.04 LTS and *should* on 16.04 as well.

```
# Use docker instead of debootstrap, could also probably use a newer version if desired
BootStrap: docker
From: ubuntu:xenial

%environment
    # note: this only active in `singularity exec` and `singularity run` steps
    export PATH=/miniconda3/bin:$PATH

%runscript
    exec vcontact "$@"

%post
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y automake build-essential bzip2 wget git default-jre unzip

    export BINPATH=/usr/local/bin

    # Install miniconda to save dependency nightmares
    wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
    bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /miniconda3/
    rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

    # pull the conda functions in
    . /miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
    # make pip, etc. available while in %post
    export PATH="/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"

    conda install -y -c conda-forge hdf5 pytables pypandoc biopython networkx numpy pandas scipy scikit-learn psutil pip
    conda install -y -c bioconda mcl blast diamond

    pip install setuptools-markdown

    # Install vContact
    git clone https://bitbucket.org/MAVERICLab/vcontact2.git
    cd vcontact2 && pip install .

    # Bug with setuptools?
    cp /vcontact2/vcontact/data/ViralRefSeq-prokaryotes-v??.* /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vcontact/data/

    # 'Install' ClusterONE
    cd / && wget http://www.paccanarolab.org/static_content/clusterone/cluster_one-1.0.jar
    mv /cluster_one-1.0.jar $BINPATH && chmod +x $BINPATH/cluster_one-1.0.jar

    # Clean stuff up
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
    conda clean --yes --tarballs --packages --source-cache

    # TACC's Stampede compliant, for iVirus/CyVerse
    mkdir /home1 && mkdir /scratch && mkdir /work
```

I put comments on the lines I changed, but please let me know if this doesn't build on your system or have questions about the changes.